# ASP.NET MVC - HttpException or return view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to make a request for a customer and if the customer doesn't exist it should return some kind of "Not found" page.  Which of the below would be the best practice to use for such a task, and why?

```
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{
    if (customerService.GetCustomerById(id) == null)
        return View("NotFound");

    return View();
}
```

or

```
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{
    if (customerService.GetCustomerById(id) == null)
        throw new HttpException(404, "Customer not found");

    return View();
}
```

Comment: What would the Exception mean to the end user? Also, why are you emitting links to non-existing Customer IDs? :)

Comment: It should just tell the end user that the user dosent exist. Answer to your second question is that if someone delete a customer, and another havent updated his/her browser yet then the link is still listed and when clicked it would throw an unexpected exception.

Comment: Just to back ebb up, what if a human enters a bad id by hand? 404.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Throw a 404. There's really no argument. It's not about being a REST disciple, it's just how the web works.

You can return a view *and* a 404. It's often helpful to help the user or present a search box or point to some top selling items, but make the NotFound clear to the customer and always return a 404 in the HTTP response. No question about that.

Edit: This is good guidance: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/03/creating-user-friendly-404-pages.html

Answer (score 2):

This is a good question (+1) as there are some differing opinions out there about when to use HTTP exception codes and when not.

REST disciples will likely tell you to go the HTTP Exception route because they believe that a URI identifies a conceptual resource (i.e.: the actual object/thing to which you are referring - a Customer in this case), and if that resource doesn't exist then you should get a 404 error back.

However, some will disagree and say that you should only pass back a 404 error if the *physical* resource, e.g. a file, doesn't exist.

I tend to fall into the second camp and would recommend that you return 200 OK with a custom view stating that the customer specified by the ID could not be found.

Comment: A custom view that takes a parameter for error message, and response code as 200 would be the way forward?

Comment: That would be my recommendation, yes. Like I said, it's just an opinion and not necessarily a codified best practice, so really you can do whatever you want.

Comment: Wouldn't it be a bit safer for SEO reasons to throw the 404?

Comment: @David - I can't comment on the SEO implications of choosing one or the other. Like I mentioned in my post, it's a matter of opinion/preference ultimately.

Comment: Yeah, I think in my case the 404 is more appropriate, can give a friendlier message.  Thinking is, technically, if someone links to 200 pages, google/crawlers might think it's a valid page, and index it, which could of course lead to some duplicate content issues.

Comment: You can display a friendly page and throw the 404 at the same time that way both people and computers can understand its not found...

Comment: So, "200: I found what you were looking for. It's this page that says I couldn't find what you were looking for." Hmm... sounds both backwards and redundant.

Comment: @ChristopherHarris I'm not the one who came up with either philosophy on the matter; I simply communicated them to OP.

Comment: I simply see no benefit in returning a 200 response when the intended resource could not be found. I'd like to read more about the other philosophy. Do you have a reference, or a name, for that other philosophy?

Comment: I don't have a name for it, no. However, at various points it was very common to return 200 with an error in the payload, and some APIs still do. I can easily recall a time when Twitter, Facebook, Google, et al all returned 200 with the error in the payload. Given that my answer is 2+ years old at the time the practice was quite common.